# how to set N prefix before sql parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i writed a query like this:

> ```
> SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] 
> FROM [WorkersView] 
> WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE '%' + N'علی' + '%' ) AND ([LastName] LIKE '%' + N'مسروری' + '%')
> ```

and it's work very well! and Gives me the desired result!

but i want send parameter to the query like this:

> ```
> SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] 
> FROM [WorkersView] 
> WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE '%' + N@FirstName + '%' ) AND ([LastName] LIKE '%' + N@LastName + '%')
> ```

that don't worked!

and also i tried this code:

> ```
> SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] 
> FROM [WorkersView] 
> WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE N'%' + @FirstName + '%' ) AND ([LastName] LIKE N'%' + @LastName + '%')
> ```

that don't worked,too! and No result returns!

my collation is Persian_100_CI_AI. and all of data type of columns in nvarchar

meantime, i have this code in asp.net :

> ```
>             <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Width="645px">
>                 <Columns>
>                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
>                     <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
>                 </Columns>
>             </asp:GridView>
>             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ResamanConnectionString %>"  SelectCommand="SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [WorkersView] WHERE (([FirstName] LIKE N'%' + @FirstName + N'%') AND ([LastName] LIKE N'%' + @LastName + N'%'))" >
>                 <SelectParameters>
>                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="firstNameTextBox" Name="FirstName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
>                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lastNameTextBox" Name="LastName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
>                 </SelectParameters>
>             </asp:SqlDataSource>
> ```

how to send parameter with this code with N prefix?

Comment: What is the data type of your parameter?

Comment: all of them is nvarchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write the query as:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] 
FROM [WorkersView] 
WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE N'%' + @FirstName + N'%' ) AND ([LastName] LIKE N'%' + @LastName + N'%')
```

The parameters should be set as:

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(255) = N'علی';
DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(255) = N'مسروری';
```

Declaring the strings to be `nvarchar()` instead of `varchar()` is the most important part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

“nvarchar“ as datatype require to save data as unicode,
and set prefix as
N'' + @parameter + N''